# Use an easing function while making an item editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I saw a few tutorials on using x-editable to make items editable on demand. After a few tries I even managed to style the editing popup according to my own css (Note I only did this for the item after it becomes editable not before).

But what I could not do was make the transition from the regular item to the editable one with an animation. Preferably [dynamics.js](http://dynamicsjs.com/) that tales care of animations automatically.

If anyone has done something similar, could you explain how can this be done?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and did not work?

Comment: It is not that I have tried and failed, I have no idea how to start. I can animate an item but only when I have created it myself (I can find it by class on my code).